# how to transfer current gridview content to crystal reports?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

i have a little problem about my project,

i have a Gridview in my form that contains data from SQL.
i'd like to transfer the current data of my gridview into crystal report

here's my code for my gridview1.

```
    ElseIf tabWaivee.SelectedTab Is tabBilling Then

        If Me.txtClaimno.Text <> "" Then
            Dim strcom2 As String = "select claim_no, period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO, who_updated, year_student from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY where CLAIM_NO like '" + txtClaimno.Text + "'"
            btnAdd.Enabled = True
            dt2.Clear()
            'Fill the data table with data from the database.
            Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(strcom2, connstr)
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt2)
            dataAdapter.Dispose()
            'Display the table in the data grid.
            DataGridView2.DataSource = dt2
            DataGridView2.Columns("claim_no").Visible = False
        Else
            If dt2.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No records found")
            End If
        End If
```

[image: here's the grid view]

what i wanna do is transfer the current gridview content into my crystal report.
through toolstripmenuItem.click

[image: here's the tool strip for report]

can someone please provide me on how to connect the dgv to my crystalreport?

i already created a crystal report for each of the data grid. the problem now is how to connect those.

```
Private Sub StudentReportsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SchoolReportsToolStripMenuItem.Click

'pls put it here.


End Sub
```

i actually have two reports to create. but i think giving 1 example is enough

Comment: try to assign dgv's datasource as the cr's datasource ...

Comment: now thats my problem. i don't know how do that. it is my first time to use crystal reports, or should i say, my first time to create a report :/